# How do I filter out comments for Draft/Closed posts?

Tags: expressionengine

In Expression Engine, I'm using {exp:comment:entries} but I need it to filter out comments for a blog post that is in draft/closed status.

```
{exp:comment:entries limit="5" dynamic="no" channel="blog"}{/exp:comment:entries}
```

It looks as though I need to work with {status} or {entry_status} but neither work as a parameter or in a conditional?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you tried this exactly:

```
{exp:comment:entries limit="5" dynamic="no" channel="blog" entry_status="not closed|draft"}{/exp:comment:entries}
```

??

That's what I would expect would work.

Comment: Yes tried it again, but still shows the comments associated with a draft post.

Comment: Any joy when you select entry status by inclusion rather than exclusion?  entry_status="open"

Comment: Yes, I tried that one too and checked case Open and open. But no joy.

Comment: I just tested this locally with EE 2.4 (the only install I have with many entries and comments), and it worked as expected. By default, only comments on "not closed" entries are shown. I passed custom statuses to "entry_status" (in my case, "closed", then "Featured", etc), and they all worked as expected. So, I don't think this is an EE bug.

Comment: I seems likely that the issue exists outside of the code snippet you have provided. Consider adding additional information: Other EE code on the page, results of turning on "display mysql queries".

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned a status group to that channel? (Admin > Channel Administration > Channels >  Edit Group Assignments > Status Groups)

I've seen issues filtering by status if the status group is set to none for that channel.